# jmeter websphere 6.1 j_security_check

Tags: jmeter, websphere-6.1, j-security-check

Can someone explain to me how to get jmeter to login.  I have an http request that goes to apps/j_security_check.  I have added two parameters j_username and j_password.  It does not seem to authenticate the user when I run this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong.  I used a Capital J in j_password causing the authentication to fail.

Thanks for every bodies help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a gander at [simulate 200 users with jmeter, each with unique logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443173/simulate-200-users-with-jmeter-each-with-unique-logins)

It may be that to login you  must pass a unique security token.

Have you tried recording the login process, to see what is captured?
If you add a "View Results Tree" you should see the exact login error.